# Reusable custom cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cell

I have a `tableView` with a `custom cell`. I have the posibility to save to favorites some of the elements , and when this is happening i want to add a star `image` in `cell`. I was trying doing this , but after the star appears, i have a problem . I think it's because of `reusable` `cell` but i dont know how to solve it .  **My problem is :** **`stars appear again on the other cells even if the word is not added on favorites.`**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    dictionaryTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (!cell) {
        cell=[[dictionaryTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.searchResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }
    else
    {
        cell.word.text = self.tableData[indexPath.row];
        BOOL isTheObjectThere = [self.favoriteArry containsObject:self.tableData[indexPath.row]];
        if (isTheObjectThere==TRUE) {
             cell.favImg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"3081@3x.png"];
        }
    }

        return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace following code in place of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. you will get your desire output.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    dictionaryTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (!cell) {
        cell=[[dictionaryTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }
   cell.favImg.hidden = YES;
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.searchResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }
    else
    {
        cell.word.text = self.tableData[indexPath.row];
        BOOL isTheObjectThere = [self.favoriteArry containsObject:self.tableData[indexPath.row]];
        if (isTheObjectThere==TRUE) {
             cell.favImg.hidden = NO;
             cell.favImg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"3081@3x.png"];
        }
    }

    return cell;

}
```

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the image if the object is not `TRUE`

```
if (isTheObjectThere==TRUE) {
   cell.favImg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"3081@3x.png"];
} else {
   cell.favImg.image=nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right it's because of reusing your cells via dequeueReusableCell with identifier as-

```
 dictionaryTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
```

according to your requirements you set a star image on a cell to indicate some favorite elements on the respective cell, like this

```
BOOL isTheObjectThere = [self.favoriteArry containsObject:self.tableData[indexPath.row]];
        if (isTheObjectThere==TRUE) {
             cell.favImg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"3081@3x.png"];
        }
```

When any cell with star image is reused than it should be removed if the next cell does not some favorite elements but if it does have some favorite elements than it should be used as-

To resolve this issue just add the else case with the above if statement as

```
if (isTheObjectThere == TRUE)
   cell.favImg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"3081@3x.png"];
 else
   cell.favImg.image=nil;
```